# Trying to connect to database via Putty with jump box

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, putty

I'm trying to use Putty to create a tunnel that MySQL Workbench can connect through.

Steps I take:

1. In putty, create a connection to Jumpbox
2. In SSH:Auth add my pem file and allow agent forwarding
3. Add the pem file to pageant
4. In SSH:Tunnels add the Source port 3307, add the destination as the Database server address in the cluster (that the Jumpbox forwards to)
5. Connect to the Jumpbox - this is successful

Then in MySQLWorkbench, try and connect to the database at localHost:3307

This fails.

Can anyone enlighten me on how to create a SSH connection via a JumpBox using Putty or find where the problem might be?

Comment: Even I have the same query. Do you know the answer?

Comment: answer below check that

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
ssh  -i KEY -L 3006:10.104.100.15:3306 -N ubuntu@jump-box
```